# Enable bass management

Tags: sound, 20.04, pulseaudio

I'm using a Razer Tiamat 7.1 headset (that is true 7.1, with 5 jack connectors). I was previously using it on a windows machine, and as it sounds pretty bad without tweaking, I made a custom equalizer  on the Realtek Audio Console. I managed to find one that makes the listening experience very pleasant with strong bass which aren't covering the higher frequencies. However, I'm struggling to make this headset sound at least a little bit better on Ubuntu (Kubuntu 20.04 to be precise).

First, I switched the audio device to "7.1 output + analog input". That worked great and all my speakers, subwoofer and microphone were working properly.

Then, I tried `pulseaudio-equalizer` and `pulseeffects` without success. I am not a sound expert at all, and I'm not looking for the perfect professional setting, just for a good listening experience.

**pulseaudio-equalizer**: I tried to reproduce the equalizer I was using on windows with `qpaeq` but it just doesn't sound at all like on windows. The sound feels flat, lacking bass and with unclear higher tones. Applying the equalizer **does** make a very slight difference though.

**pulseeffects**: I tried to reproduce the equalizer as well, giving a result similar to the `qpaeq` one, but with occasional crackling. I tried many options and filters, with no success. I also tried all of these [presets](https://github.com/JackHack96/PulseEffects-Presets), but none of them made a big difference. Even cranking up the settings a tiny bit made the sound extremely distorted and crackling.

On windows (Realtek Audio Console), the setting that makes the biggest difference is "**Enable Bass Management**". It makes everything clearer and each sound feels more "separated", and the bass is sounding like it's supposed to. I couldn't find any setting that give similar results on Ubuntu, so I think that "Enable Bass Management" adds some audio filters and tweaks under the hood. I just don't know which ones.

My question is:

- Do you know any way to enable a similar option on Ubuntu?
- Do you know what it does under the hood and how to reproduce it in PulseEffects?
- If not, do you know any friendly piece of software for audio noobs like me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally got it to sound quite good! After digging up and learning about how sound works, I found a lot of valuable information. There were many steps.

First, I noticed only the left and right speakers were actually used by applications using stereo (two channels). But the Tiamat has 8 channels. Here are the steps to fix this issue:

- going into the audio settings -> advanced and set card to "Analog Surround 7.1 Output + Analaog Stereo Input"
- Create a file `~/.config/pulse/daemon.conf`

```
resample-method = speex-float-7
enable-remixing = yes
remixing-produce-lfe = yes
remixing-consume-lfe = yes
lfe-crossover-freq = 120
default-sample-channels = 8
```

This enables remixing, which is the process of mixing the stereo channels and output them to the other available channels (side, rear, center and subwoofer). This is what makes the biggest difference.

I also changed the resample method. By default, I was using speex-float-1, which produced a lot of crackling and distortion. With speex-float-7, I don't notice them anymore.

Now that all the speakers are working, I used pulseeffects to tweak the sound.

- Enable "Limiter" and move it all the way up so it's first in the chain. Set "Input Gain" at -8dB and leave "Limit" at 0dB
- Enable "Equalizer" and tune it to make the sound feel how you like.
- Enable "Bass enhancer" and set amount to 2dB.
- Disable everything else

Now it sounds way better!

Comment: Great answer! The only thing missing is explaining what "bass management" actually does. When home theater or multi-channel HiFi -equipment speaks about bass management, it means remixing lowest bass to different speakers. Most often this means main L+R speakers or the subwoofer. This improves audio quality because this remixing takes info about the speakers as input and can avoid passing low frequency signals to small speakers. This allows speaker to use all the power for higher frequencies only which improves audio quality.

Comment: Unless you have a subwoofer with DSP room correction I would recommend using 80-100 Hz FRE crossover frequency. Otherwise you'll experience lots of room modes which will also reduce the overall audio quality.

Comment: @MikkoRantalainen I changed lfe-crossover-freq to 100 and it sound slightly better, thanks!

Comment: I have DSpeaker 8033 (http://www.dspeaker.com/en/products/anti-mode-8033.shtml) adjusting the subwoofer output and then having pretty high (100-120 Hz) LFE crossover frequency can make sense. However, note that such DSP processing causes extra delay (2.7 ms in case of DSpeaker 8033) and you have to add delay correction to all other channels. I have AV receiver taking care of bass management and 2.7 ms delay so I don't know if pulseaudio can do that. For best results, you want channel dependant delay to get all sound impulses to align correctly.

Comment: In my experience, stereo image may change even with 0.2 ms delay between the front channels (e.g. center channel having 0.2 ms delay compared to L+R) if you play average of L+R in the center channel.

Comment: If you're interested in more technical side of audio reproduction, I suggest checking out REW: https://www.roomeqwizard.com/

Comment: It seems that it's possible to use BruteFIR https://wiki.slimdevices.com/index.php/Brutefir_Filter.html after generating DSP correction files using REW. `apt install brutefir` will get you the DSP prosessor software but I don't know how you're supposed to configure it to be used in default output. Unfortunately, the original web pages are offline. Last known copy from Wayback machine: https://web.archive.org/web/20160829073501/http://www.ludd.luth.se/~torger/brutefir.html

Comment: See here for extra info if you want to create software DSP: https://th0ma5w.github.io/DIY-Room-Correction/ -- basically you can create virtual soundcard with ALSA, use e.g. BruteFIR to process audio passed through that soundcard and output to your real audio output. If you decide to go this route, please, report what you did and did you succeed! And if you get any measurement mic, get UMIK-1 or UMIK-2.

Comment: Here's a link to somebody else implementing room correction using just PulseAudio and `ladspa_dsp` plugin. Note the part where you need to reduce incoming audio volume if your filters need to boost some specific frequencies - you really don't want to go over 0 dB for any input signal because that would cause clipping and heavy distortion.